# WinForms Range Bar Chart Axis Not Rendering as Expected

Tags: winforms, charts, range

I am attempting to generate a ranged bar chart using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.RangeBar.  When I add the x axis as integers it renders correctly as shown below:

```
        int[] x = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
        int[] y = { 10, 2, 35, 1, 10, 20 };
        int[] y2 = { 35, 4, 36, 2, 15, 40 };
        var xValue = x.ToList();
        var yValue1 = y.ToList();
        var yValue2 = y2.ToList();

        chart2.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y, y2);
```

[image: Correctly Rendered Chart]

However, when I swap the x axis integers to strings the chart does not render as above:

```
        string[] x = { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1" };
        int[] y = { 10, 2, 35, 1, 10, 20 };
        int[] y2 = { 35, 4, 36, 2, 15, 40 };
        var xValue = x.ToList();
        var yValue1 = y.ToList();
        var yValue2 = y2.ToList();
        chart2.Series[0].XValueType = 
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String;

        chart2.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y, y2);
```

[image]

Is there an elegant workaround to using string values for the x-axis while maintaining int or DateTime values for the y axis?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it!

```
            int[] tmpx = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
            string[] x = { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1" };
            int[] y = { 10, 2, 35, 1, 10, 20 };
            int[] y2 = { 35, 4, 36, 2, 15, 40 };
            //var xValue = x.ToList();
            //var yValue1 = y.ToList();
            //var yValue2 = y2.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i<x.Length; i++)
            {
                int index = chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(tmpx[i], y[i], y2[i]);
                chart1.Series[0].Points[index].AxisLabel = x[i];
            }
```